# Use client side rendering(js link) for dynamically created Sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, event-receiver, jslink, sharepoint-addin

I want to use client side rendering(js link) for document library, the challenge for me is Sharepoint document library will be created dynamically when the remote event receiver triggers.

I know we need to pass js link reference in elements.xml file, but in my case list will be created later, so how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add script (JSLink) programmatically, after your condition event receiver:

C#:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/test"))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
                SPFile page = web.GetFile("SitePages/Test.aspx");
                page.CheckOut();
                using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpmgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                {
                    XmlElement p = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("p");
                    p.InnerText = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello World');</script>";
                    ContentEditorWebPart cewp = new ContentEditorWebPart
                    {
                        Content = p
                    };
                    wpmgr.AddWebPart(cewp, "Header", 0);
                }
                page.CheckIn(String.Empty);
            }
```

JS:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection/Default.aspx';

function addWebPart() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    var webPartXml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>' + 
        '<WebPart xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"' + 
        ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"' + 
        ' xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2\">' + 
        '<Title>My Web Part</Title><FrameType>Default</FrameType>' + 
        '<Description>Use for formatted text, tables, and images.</Description>' + 
        '<IsIncluded>true</IsIncluded><ZoneID></ZoneID><PartOrder>0</PartOrder>' + 
        '<FrameState>Normal</FrameState><Height /><Width /><AllowRemove>true</AllowRemove>' + 
        '<AllowZoneChange>true</AllowZoneChange><AllowMinimize>true</AllowMinimize>' + 
        '<AllowConnect>true</AllowConnect><AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>' + 
        '<AllowHide>true</AllowHide><IsVisible>true</IsVisible><DetailLink /><HelpLink />' + 
        '<HelpMode>Modeless</HelpMode><Dir>Default</Dir><PartImageSmall />' + 
        '<MissingAssembly>Cannot import this Web Part.</MissingAssembly>' + 
        '<PartImageLarge>/_layouts/images/mscontl.gif</PartImageLarge><IsIncludedFilter />' + 
        '<Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ' + 
        'PublicKeyToken=94de0004b6e3fcc5</Assembly>' + 
        '<TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart</TypeName>' + 
        '<ContentLink xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + '/sites/SiteAssets/Test.js</ContentLink>' + 
        '<Content xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\">' + 
        '<![CDATA[This is a first paragraph!<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>And this is a second paragraph.]]></Content>' + 
        '<PartStorage xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor\" /></WebPart>';

    var oWebPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.importWebPart(webPartXml);
    this.oWebPart = oWebPartDefinition.get_webPart();
    limitedWebPartManager.addWebPart(oWebPart, 'Left', 1);
    clientContext.load(oWebPart);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Web Part added: ' + oWebPart.get_title());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```